# (Python - pyautogui) TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I'm beginner with Mac. I was trying to get a picture position (Simple thing)
But i don't understand what do i have to do.

```
import time
import pyautogui


image_test = "test.jpeg"

image_location_3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image_test,confidence=0.8, grayscale = True)

print(image_location_3)
```

The error was....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/academianamu/Desktop/Coding/googlemeetautoadmit.py", line 16, in <module>
    image_location_3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image_test,confidence=0.8, grayscale = True)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 172, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 210, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 375, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 527, in _screenshot_osx
    if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

To resolve this kinds of error.

Comment: PIL.__version__ returns a string, i.e. `'6.2.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the perfect answer but it worked for me. Open Finder and click Go and Go to the folder. Type in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py`

this should open a Python file and scroll down to line 527 and comment out (by using #) all the lines that deal with the if statement and only have the line "`im = ImageGrab.grab()`"

Then you should be able to use `pyautogui.pixel` to find RGB values. `displayMousePosition()` still doesn't work for some reason.